# How to recolor artwork while preserving shading?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, vector

I want to change the red flower to blue but whats the fastest way to match it with the shading and make it look good? Or do I have to manually put colors?

[image: Recolor Artwork]

Answer (score 2):

I propose you to click on the **Edit** tab ("Modifier" on my screenshot), then you can lock the color harmony (at the **red circles**). With Shift+drag, your saturation rate will be protected, but the hue will be changed.

I hope it will help you.

[image: enter Illustrator Color swap]